# Solving the equation of the form $a - \frac{1}{x}\ln{(\frac{x}{1-x})} + \frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-functions

I got an equation of the form $a - \frac{1}{x}\ln{\frac{x}{1-x}} + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$. $a$ is a constant and the values of $x \in [0,1]$.

Does a closed-form solution exist for this? If not, is there any approximate solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Do you have any information about the size of $a$?

Comment: @Shew To prevent downvoting and closing the question, you should add information about your background and where your equation comes from.

Comment: graphically we can see that for $a>4$ basically it solves to $x\approx 1$ and for $a<-4$ the $1/x^2$ term is dominant. best chance I think would be to find a simpler approximant in the range $a\in[-4,4]$, maybe something like log of a rational function. Anyway I would separate these $3$ intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer:

$$a-\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)+\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$
$$x^2a-x\ln\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)+1=0$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,\ln\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$x\to \frac{e^t}{1+e^t}$:
$$\frac{ae^{2t}-te^t-te^{2t}+2e^t+e^{2t}+1}{(e^t+1)^2}=0$$
$$a(e^t)^2-t(e^t)^2+(e^t)^2-te^t+2e^t+1=0$$

We see, the equation is an algebraic equation of both $t$ and $e^t$ with no univariate factor. The equation cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) therefore.

And we see, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W.